# How to deal with awk commas using paramiko on Django?

Tags: django, bash, paramiko

```
stdout = session.exec_command('''find {} -name "{}*" -type f -exec stat -c "%n %y" {}<--**This is bash, not variable of format** + | awk "{ print $1" "$2 }" | grep -v word'''
.format(VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2))
```

I'm doing this code using paramiko 2.4 on Django 1.9.13, don't know how to deal with it, the error is:

> KeyError at /get_xml/index/ ' print $1" "$2 '

**UPDATED**:

It doesn't crash right now, but doesn't returns anything, but if I do on bash, it's working, think there's missing something...

```
command = find {} -name '{}*.xml' -type f -exec stat -c '%n %y' {{}} + | awk '{{print $1, $2, $3}}' | grep -v 'word'

stdout = session.exec_command(command)
```

**ANSWER**

```
ssh.connect(hostname=VARIABLE1, username=VARIABLE2)
command = "find {} -name '{}*.xml' -type f -exec stat -c '%n %y' {{}} + | awk '{{print $1, $2, $3}}' | grep -v WHATIDONTWANTTO".format(VARIABLE3, WHATIWANTTOSEARCH)
_, stdout, _ = ssh.exec_command(command)
for item in stdout:
     #do whatever with items
     pass
```

finally it works, the last way was with session = ssh.get_transport().open_session() but it always retrieve 'Nonetype'

Comment: VARIABLE3 is missing.

Comment: updated, it belongs to bash command, is NOT a variable from python

Comment: awk "{ print $1,$2 }"   <file_name>. where is your file name here ?

Comment: That `awk` won't work, due to the double quotes. Change it to `awk '{print $1 " " $2}'` or even simpler, `awk '{print $1, $2}'`

Comment: In addition to the curly brace problem, you can't use double quotes inside a double-quoted string. Your Awk script should probably be single-quoted instead. (Also, avoid the [useless use of `grep`;](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) or, better yet, do the output filtering in Python.)

Comment: Do you really have `<--**This is bash, not variable of format**` inside that string, or is that supposed to be a comment?

Comment: comment for y'all

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation on `.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), if you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}.

So this `-exec stat -c "%n %y" {}` should be `-exec stat -c "%n %y" {{}}` and so on, if I understood your comment correctly.